# What dictates the order of languages used by the UN?

Tags: united-nations, languages

In the image below, what dictates the order of the languages on the top banner (e.g. why English and *then* French?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The rules don't provide](https://www.un.org/en/ga/about/ropga/lang.shtml) any directive on order of languages. It seems likely that the order is "Alphabetical in English".

So Arabic (the only right-to-left language is placed first (on the right). Then the left-to-right languages are in alphabetical order Chinese, English, French, Russian, Spanish, from left-to-right

The [rules of procedure of the security council](https://www.un.org/securitycouncil/content/rop/chapter-8) name these as the official and working languages in alphabetical order.

Comment: Any vertical ordering example?

Comment: Well look at the image.  The only language that can be written vertically is Chinese, and it is written horizontally.  So, no the question doesn't contain a vertical example.